# how to solve this apache tile config problem

Tags: spring-boot, maven, config, apache-tiles

hello i have made an webapp based this course

[apache Tiles](https://o7planning.org/11683/spring-boot-apache-tiles-jsp)

but it gives error when creating a beans of TilesConfig.java

also it is my app source
[app file](https://ufile.io/5fete8x1)

and my log file

```
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.708 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.cafe2.webapp.WebappApplicationTests
contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in class path resource [com/cafe2/webapp/config/TilesConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No URL for ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No URL for ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Comment: It's not "titles" its "tiles"

Comment: it was just a mistake

Comment: Could you please add the error what you are getting with the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your config package and controller package at same level.
ice `package org.o7planning.sbtiles.*;`. Reduce the package level for SpringBootJspTilesApplication class OR increase the package level for TilesConfig and MainController classes. Because class annotated with @SpringBootApplication start scanning base packages from this level only.

Please consider defining controller and config package as below:
limit SpringBootJspTilesApplication be in `package org.o7planning.sbtiles;`
TilesConfig be in `package org.o7planning.sbtiles.config;`
MainController be in `package org.o7planning.sbtiles.controller;`

Comment: it didnt work for me i even used component scan in my config

Comment: i geass problem is case of apache tiles